# Having issue parsing SVG image

Tags: android, svg

I am trying to parse an SVG image and i did it successfully but the issue is the image is not parsed properly,it is being cut at some places.I would appreciate the help.

```
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.svg)
        SVG svg= SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.magnify);
        Drawable drawable=svg.createPictureDrawable();
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the SVG file?

Comment: No,If i convert it to vector asset it is working perfectly but i wanna load svg images directly from the server.

Comment: Please read the documentation of your current library. Not all are working the same. Maybe your svg file is compressed and your current library doesn't support that. Or it uses gradients or text.

Comment: You appear to be using svg-android. It has problems with some SVG files. Perhaps that is your problem. It is hard to tell without seeing the SVG file. You could try the AndroidSVG library instead, which has more complete SVG support.